# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (AuthRepository, ?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT into my project. I've followed the steps as outline in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/jwt#usage

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthRepository } from './auth.repository';

@Module({
    imports: [
        JwtModule.register({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'ABCDE12345' }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AuthRepository]),
    ],
    exports: [TypeOrmModule, AuthService],
    providers: [AuthService],
    controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AuthEntity } from './auth.entity';
import { LoginDTO } from './dto/login.dto';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { AuthRepository } from './auth.repository';

// export interface FindWhereData {
//     readonly email: string;
//     readonly password: string;
// }

export interface LoginResponse {
    readonly token: string;
    readonly refresh_token: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(AuthRepository)
        private authRepository: AuthRepository,
        private jwtService: JwtService
    ) {}

    /**
     * Login user service
     *
     * @param doc
     */
    public async login(doc: LoginDTO): Promise<LoginResponse> {
        // verify user email
        const user = await this.authRepository.findOne({ email: doc.email });

        if (!user) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Could not find user');
        }
        // verify password
        const passwordsMatch = await this.passwordsAreEqual(doc.password, user.password);
        if (!passwordsMatch) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Incorrect login credentials');
        }

        // generate JWT
        const token = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ id: user.id });

        // create the refresh token
        const refreshToken = crypto.randomBytes(256).toString('hex');

        // store the refresh token

        return {
            token: token,
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
        };
    }

    /**
     * Generate a hashed password
     *
     * @param password
     */
    public async hashPassword(password: string): Promise<string> {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();

        return await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    }

    /**
     * Compare password against an encrypted string
     *
     * @param password
     * @param encryptedPassword
     */
    public async passwordsAreEqual(password: string, encryptedPassword: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, encryptedPassword);
    }

    /**
     * Find a record by column attribute and value
     *
     * @param queryObject
     *
     */
    public async findWhere(queryObject): Promise<AuthEntity> {
        const authEntity = await this.authRepository.findOne({ where: queryObject });

        if (!authEntity) {
            return null;
        }

        return authEntity;
    }

    public async findOne(id: string): Promise<AuthEntity> {
        return this.authRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

**auth.repository.ts**

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { AuthEntity } from "./auth.entity";

@EntityRepository(AuthEntity)
export class AuthRepository extends Repository<AuthEntity> {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RouterModule } from 'nest-router';
import { routes } from './routes';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import configuration from './config/configuration';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoutes(routes),
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [configuration],
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST || 'localhost',
            port: 5432,
            username: process.env.POSTGRES_USERNAME || 'postgres',
            password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || 'password',
            database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE || 'service-auth',
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: true,
        }),
        AuthModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private readonly connection: Connection) {
        console.log('connection status: ' + connection.isConnected);
    }
}
```

**auth.service.spec.ts**

```
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AuthEntity } from './auth.entity';
import { AuthRepository } from './auth.repository';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

describe('AuthService', () => {
    let authService: AuthService;
    let authRepository: AuthRepository;
    const mockAuthRepository = () => ({
        login: jest.fn(),
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                AuthService,
                // JwtModule,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(AuthRepository),
                    useFactory: mockAuthRepository,
                },
                {
                    provide: JwtService,
                    useValue: {
                        signAsync: jest.fn(() => 'token'),
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).compile();

        authService = await module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
        authRepository = await module.get<AuthRepository>(AuthRepository);
    });

    /**
     * Test that the service is defined
     */
    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(authService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

When I run `npm run test` I get the following error message:

```
FAIL  src/auth/auth.service.spec.ts
  ● AuthService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (AuthRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
      })
```

I know the error is probably pretty clear to seasoned Node/Nest developer but I cannot figure out what the RootTestModule is and how to get JwtModule imported.

I believe I have followed the setup correctly but adding this JwtModule to the AuthService is causing the service to be undefined in my unit tests.

**Repo**
https://github.com/marcuschristiansen/nestjs-auth

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding a custom provider for the `JwtService` so that you can mock it. A custom provider could look like

```js
{
  provide: JwtService,
  useValue: {
    signAsync: jest.fn(() => 'token'),
  }
}
```

To tell Nest to inject an object that has a `signAsync()` method that when called returns the string `'token'` so that it will always be the same in your tests.

This object goes in the `providers` array, just like the `AuthRepository` mock

Comment: Please have a look at my edit of **auth.service.spec.ts** 

Now getting 

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument AuthRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Comment: `AuthRepository` should acutally be `getRepositoryToken(AuthRepository)` so that you get the proper injection token that Nest is expecting

Comment: Hmm, looks fine to me. Can you provide a link to your repository?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/marcuschristiansen/nestjs-auth

Comment: Your `auth.service.spec` runs as expected. The error comes from your `auth.controller.spec` because `AuthService` isn't mocked there, so it's looking for `AuthSerivce`'s dependencies.